# Failed to execute maven-enforcer-plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, uima

I am trying to install UIMA JDK with maven. However, there's always a waring

---

```
Rule 0: org.semver.enforcer.RequireBackwardCompatibility failed with message:
Current codebase is not backward compatible (BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE_IMPLEMENTER) with version <2.7.0>. Compatibility type has been detected as <BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE_USER>
```

and then error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-compatibility) on project uimaj-core: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.

Please help me fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are considering to switch to semantic versioning. I changed the configuration in UIMA trunk yesterday to check if according to semantic versioning the next version should be 2.7.1 or 2.8.0.

You can change the compatibility check back - or - you should just use the last stable release 2.7.0 from Maven Central instead of building yourself.

To change it back, open `uimaj-parent/pom.xml` and set:

```
<compat.level>BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE_USER</compat.level>
```

*Disclosure: It was me that broke the build ;)*